# How to install gRPC plugin in on-prem k8s cluster. I am new to this

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

I have 3 control planes and 2 master modes and wanted to secure etcd using kms. So i wanted to deploy kms plugin but don’t know how to do this. Please help. In K8s docs, installation of plugin is not given

Expecting to install kms plugin